# Highlight text stored in cookie with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i have to do these tasks with javascript. i have tried several ways but none of them worked.

1. highlight selected text -done
2. store highlighted text's start and end index in cookie so that if user comes again to this page in same session then it should be highlighted- done
3. ****now i have start and end index of the text in a cookie in the document i have to highlight that text****  i have stored start and end index in two arrays from cookie.

if i store text in the cookie and on page load replace it with formatted text then i would replace first occurrence of the text which may be the text which is not the next whose start index and end index is sored in array.

i have to find some other way which takes start and end index for highligting the text

plz help

Comment: perhaps try using a regular expression to find your start point? just an idea.

Comment: i have start and end index of the text. but dont know how to highlight it

Comment: How are you getting the start and end index of the selected text? What are they relative to?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Rangy's serializer module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SerializerModule) ([demo](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/serializer.html))?

Disclosure: I am Rangy's author.